# Automatically stop numbers increasing

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to stop a number increasing after it hits 2^53 -1 to avoid precision error, without using hundreds of if conditions?

I have a code like this:

```
var MAX = 9007199.....; //2^53
var X1, X2, X3, .... , Xn;

//some code that works on number (note: there are no for no while, otherwise it would be easy)

if (X1 >= MAX)
   X1 = MAX;
if (........)
   ....
if (Xn >= MAX)
   Xn = MAX;
```

I can't really do an if (or maybe a function call) for every single variable in my code!
I hope some one knows a good solution, assuming it does exist.

Thank you.

Comment: is this a recursive type of question on a test or something?

Comment: "note: there are no for no while" does this mean there can be no for or no while or does it just mean there are no for or while YET, but you can write it?

Comment: Why can't there be for or while?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve, it looks like there is an easier way...

Comment: @Gil probably because that's what the prof said

Comment: how do you exactly **increase** the number?

Comment: @Huangism Yeah that's what I'm thinking as well, but I don't want to jump to conclusions impulsively :)

Comment: What do you mean by "stop"? If you truncate to Number.MAX_VALUE you are introducing more problems than precision issues. If you want to handle specific values wrap the number in a class with .add() methods and perform bounds checks.

Comment: There aren't (and I don't think there will be) any for/while just because it's not the case to use them and because I'm trying to achieve the less complicated and shorter code possible. Also the increments are not the same each time... An by "stop" I mean what I wrote in the code (the if statements), I just want to do it in a less boring, more compact way.

Comment: You could extend Number to allow; `X1 = X1.maxTruncated()` or create a `X1.safeValue` property that always return 2^53 if it value is greater

Comment: @Alex K. Do you mean that would be like a step function, or like the "conversion" of a value greater than number.MAX_VALUE in infinity? Because, I'm not sure if and how could be realised the second one...

Comment: `X1 = X1.maxTruncated()` would be exactly the same as `if (X1 >= MAX) X1 = MAX`, the `X1.safeValue` would hide the *real* value and always guarantee a value <= MAX by capping its result to MAX.

Comment: So doesn't they do the same thing?

Comment: No, `X1 = X1.maxTruncated()` would *replace* `X1` the property hides the true value; http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/d2LrM/

Comment: Oh I understood the difference, maxtruncate() modify the variable itself, safevalue instead just return 2^53 if j is >= 2^53 or j itself if it is < 2^53. Then i have to go with the first one... Well thank you very much! :P